# Custom jQuery slider for html elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to add a slider to animate some paragraphs at my home screen. 
I don't want to use any plugin.
I want to create it myself using jQuery. But there is a problem, it seems that condition in jQuery is not working.

Please checkout following codes and try to fix it.

```
<div id="slider-viewport">
  <div class="slider">
    <p>1 Cloud based e-commerce solution for your downloadable products</p>
    <p>2 Cloud based e-commerce solution for your downloadable products</p>
    <p>3 Cloud based e-commerce solution for your downloadable products</p>
    <p>4 Cloud based e-commerce solution for your downloadable products</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slider p {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
}

#slider-viewport {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.slider p').first().clone().appendTo('#slider-viewport .slider')

    function slider() {

        var $slider = $('#slider-viewport .slider');
        var currentMargin = $slider.css('margin-top');
        var paraHeight = $('.slider p').height();
        var setMargin = parseInt(currentMargin) - paraHeight;
        var resetMargin = -300;

        if (currentMargin < resetMargin) {
            $slider.css('margin-top', 0);
        };

        $slider.animate({
            marginTop: setMargin
        }, {
            duration: 600,
            easing: "easeOutQuint"
            }
        );
    };

    setInterval(slider, 3000);

});
```

Comment: have you imported the easing plugin too? or are you just using JQuery? remove easing from code and try!

Comment: Yes I've easing plugin too.

Comment: sliding is working but it is doesn't reset margin-top to 0 when currentMargin < resetMargin

Comment: Checkout [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xh9SM/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify things a bit by animating the first element only and then resetting and putting it back at the end of the list after the animation, also you can avoid `setInterval()` by making the function recursive

```
function slider() {
    var $slider = $('#slider-viewport .slider');
    var $first = $slider.find('p:first');

    $first.delay(3000).animate({'margin-top': $first.height() * -1}, 600, "easeOutQuint", function () {
        $(this).css('margin-top', 0).appendTo($slider);
        slider();
    }); 
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    slider(); 
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xh9SM/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentMargin = $slider.css('margin-top').split('px')[0];

$slider.css('margin-top', '0px');
```

Update

```
$(document).ready(function() {

setInterval(slider, 3000);

});


var $slider = $('#slider-viewport .slider'); 
var marginNew = $('.slider p').height();
var limit=marginNew*$('.slider p').length;

function slider() {            

    if(marginNew>=limit)
       marginNew=0;            

    $slider.animate({"margin-top":-marginNew});

    marginNew+=100;      


};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xh9SM/2/

Comment: Do you want to stop the slide from getting fast? Is that the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Here

http://jsfiddle.net/sk5wq/4/

#### html code:

```
<div id="slider-viewport">
  <div class="slider">
    <p>1 Cloud based e-commerce solution for your downloadable products</p>
    <p>2 Cloud based e-commerce solution for your downloadable products</p>
    <p>3 Cloud based e-commerce solution for your downloadable products</p>
    <p>4 Cloud based e-commerce solution for your downloadable products</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### css code:

```
.slider p {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
}

#slider-viewport {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

#### update js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(initSlider, 3000);
});

function initSlider() {

var slider = $('#slider-viewport .slider'),
    sliderMargin = parseInt(slider.css('margin-top')),
    pHeight = parseInt(slider.find('p').height()),
    sliderGep = '-'+(parseInt(slider.height())-pHeight),
    go = 0;   

    if (sliderMargin <= sliderGep) {
        slider.animate({marginTop:pHeight+'px'},0);
        go = '0px'
    }else{
        go = '-='+pHeight+'px'
    }

    slider.animate({
        marginTop: go
    }, {
        duration: 600,
        easing: "easeOutQuint"
    });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't always slide up. When you reset margin to 0 it slides down all 4 paragraphs. It must always slide up while looping these 4 paragraphs.